# Can I access a Thunderbolt drive with the AirPort Extreme?

Tags: airport, thunderbolt

Is there a way to connect a Thunderbolt hard drive to an [AirPort Extreme?](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD031/airport-extreme-base-station?afid=p219%7CMSUS&cid=AOS-US-KWM)

Comment: Your title and your post are two different questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, the only storage ports on the Airport Extreme is a USB port. So, if your Thunderbolt drive has a USB connector as well, then you can use it, otherwise you will have to wait for Apple to make a Airport Extreme with a Thunderbolt connector.

Comment: And it's pretty hard to imagine why they would do that. :)